# Using 'break' in a javascript switch with a if statement

Tags: javascript

Need to change the background color of a table data element each time it is clicked.  Each table data has a unique id.  Global var td1 is declared with initial value of 0. Value is changed in the switch statement to either 0 or 1.  First click always is 'yellow', but so is the next click, where it should change to 'blue' and then back to 'yellow', etc.

I tried just 'else' and then 'else if' with the same result.

Thanks for your help

```
    function changebg(elem)
    {
    td_id=elem.id;

    switch (td_id)
    {
    case "a1" :
      if(td1 = 0)
      {  
      elem.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      td1=1;
      break;
      }

    else if (td1 = 1)
      {
      elem.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
      td1=0;
      break;
      }

    case "a2" :
    elem.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
    break; 
    }
    }
```

The call to the function is 'onclick(this)' (snippit: table actually has several rows).

```
    <tr>
    <td onclick="changebg(this)" id="a1">1
    <td onclick="changebg(this)" id="a2"> 2
    </tr>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend closing all your tags properly (i.e. `td`)

Then it is good practice to initialize the variables you need to avoid unexpected results.

```js
var td1 = 0; // init flag

function changebg(elem) {
  td_id = elem.id;

  switch (td_id) {
    case "a1":
      if (td1 == 0) {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
        td1 = 1;

      } else if (td1 == 1) {
        elem.style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        td1 = 0;

      }
      break;

    case "a2":
      elem.style.backgroundColor = "yellow";
      break;
  }
}
```

```html
<table>

  <tr>
    <td onclick="changebg(this)" id="a1">1</td>
    <td onclick="changebg(this)" id="a2">2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 3):

Test for equality is `==`; `=` is used for assignment.

Comment: Changed to 'if (td1 == 0)' and 'else if (td1 == 1)' with same result.  Still not changing the background except for the first click.